# Exporting data from Graylog to compile stats

Tags: graylog2, graylog

We are thinking of using Graylog to collect logs data that will be later used to compile stats and display them on graphs (in another application). I am aware that you can create widgets/custom dashboards on Graylog web interface but is it possible to get access and manipulate these data and run queries like we do in SQL - SELECT COUNT(*) .. GROUP BY COLUMN etc?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [Graylog API](https://www.graylog.org/tips-tricks-2-using-the-graylog-rest-api/). Quoting the website:

> The use cases are endless with Graylog’s REST API. [...] Some users have built their own web interface with very specific workflows for support teams on top of the Graylog REST API. All configuration and maintenance can be performed through API calls.